# Regex match every dot

Tags: regex

I'd like to match every dot or comma but not in href attribute. So I have this regular expression: 
`^(?!.*?href=)(.*?)([.,])(\S+)`
But it matches only the first occurrence. I think it because of non-greedy `.*?` But I can't come up with anything else. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string and the parts you'd like to match?

Comment: Flavor? C#? JavaScript?

Comment: Pull out the text first and then match it. You can’t parse HTML with regexes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8492116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do to match every dot or comma and assuming that the attribute value is between single or double quotes is to match what you don't want and to capture in a group what you want to keep.

If you don't want to match a dot in the href you could match it with `href="` followed by `[^"]*"` or `'[^']*'`. Then you could use an alternation `|` to capture in a group a dot or a comma using `([.,])`

[`href=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')|([.,])`](https://regex101.com/r/euyCpW/1)

Comment: A good example of [The Best Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). +1

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match every occurrence, you will need to run the regex with the global (g) flag:
e.g.

```
/^(?!.*?href=)(.*?)([.,])(\S+)/g
```

I suggest you use a tool such as https://regex101.com/ to test and debug your regular expressions, it's super handy!

Comment: This is not a good approach. It simply [can't work](https://regex101.com/r/ljMMDL/1) even on the regex tester page.